# New face generator from Nvidia

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I have just found the paper and documentation about GAN 2.0, the new face creator from Nvidia.

On the website https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/ they have used this approach to create realistic faces. Unfortunately, the website does not exist anymore.

Is there another webpage demonstrating the new face creator from Nvidia?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a [decent sized collection on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/*/thispersondoesnotexist.com). Just browse through the snapshots and they'll contain a few images. It probably doesn't contain every single one, but it has quite a decent set to start from. :)

Here's one I found:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a Youtube video: [Nvidia - AI for Generating High-Resolution Images - Tero Karras](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrVDfX9XFpE)

I don't know about webpages.